# Show that: $f(\theta)=\sin\theta\cos(\theta\ -k)$ is max when $\theta = \frac{k+90^{\circ}}{2}$ without using calculus.

Tags: trigonometry

Given $$f(\theta)=\sin\theta\cos(\theta\ -k)$$

Show that $f(\theta)$ is maximum when: $\theta = \frac{k+90^{\circ}}{2}$

I can do this easily using calculus, but I'm looking for a way of doing it without calculus.

Context:

A particle is projected up an inclined slope. The incline is fixed at an angle $k$ to the horizontal. The particle is projected at an angle $\theta$ to the incline. This problem resulted from trying to find the angle of maximum range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note $$\sin\theta \cos(\theta-k) = \frac 12\cdot 2\sin\theta\cos(\theta-k) =\frac 12 \left(\sin(2\theta-k) +\sin k \right) $$ This will be maximum, when $$\sin(2\theta-k) =1 \\ \implies 2\theta-k=\frac{\pi}{2} +2n\pi \\ \implies \theta=\frac 12\left (k+\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi \right)$$ for any integer $n$. $|\theta|$ can be minimized by setting $n=0$.

Comment: +1 Why has it been downvoted?

Comment: -@Koro, correct. It happened with me, too. It might be because OP didn't provide context and still @Tavish has answered it.

Comment: @SarGe Yet the post is not closed and has been upvoted $3$ times?